# How did Brian blow out the floor plate in his car?

Tags: realism, fast-and-furious-franchise, fast-and-furious-1

In [*The Fast & The Furious* (2001)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0232500/), during Brian's first race with Dominic Toretto, he engages the NOS and the car has a burst of speed.  During that burst, the front floor plate of his car comes flying off.

Would something like that seriously happen to a car?  If so, in layman's terms, what would cause it?

Comment: It's unrealistic as hell... The laptop reads "Danger to Manifold" (which is in the engine) and then the floor pan falls out? The two are not connected in any way I can think of...

Comment: I know **zero** about cars, except how to change a headlight, so I figured I'd ask and hopefully someone with more knowledge than me could answer.

Comment: Dave is right here. It doesn't make any sense unless the movie explains it, which it doesn't. Simply dramatic effect, though they could have been more accurate with the same result.

Comment: There are a whole pile of inaccuracies in the films (fun as they are!).  One bit of dialog in the same scene has Toretto mocking Brian for "Not double clutching like ya should" when actually double clutching would slow down any gear changes significantly.  Check https://www.moviemistakes.com/film459/factual for reference to both the question asked and the point I mention here

Comment: @Dave - You feel like turning the info on that linked page into an answer for a quick 25 points?  Figured I'd give you first crack at it.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Happy to :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [Movie Mistakes factual errors listing](https://www.moviemistakes.com/film459/factual) this really couldn't have happened:

> During the first race a square plate on the floor falls off Brian's
>   Eclipse. The Mitsubishi Eclipse is a unibody car; the frame and body
>   are built as one solid piece, and it does not have floor pans. While
>   some racers might put a steel plate in the interior as a finishing
>   piece, it would be cosmetic only and not part of the vehicle's
>   structure.

It's one of several unrealistic things in the franchise, but it's great fun to watch so well worth it anyways.

Comment: plot device....

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - How is it even a plot device?